# Find Pairs in Array with same mean as the Array

Tags: arrays, c, average, complexity-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem where I have to identify the number of pairs in an array that have the same mean/average as the original array.

Though I have solved the problem with nested loops(refer to the code below), I wanted to reduce the complexity of my solution, and I'm not getting any ideas so far.

Update: 'T' is just a variable representing the number of test cases. You can assume that to be 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comparator(const void *p, const void *q) {
  int l = *(int *)p;
  int r = *(int *)q;
    return (l-r);
}
    
int fSum(int *Arr, int N){
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        sum+=Arr[i];
        }

    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    int i=1, T, N, pos = 1, j=0, k=0, c = 0, sum;
    int Arr[100000];
    
    scanf("%d",&T);

    while(i<=T){
     scanf("%d", &N);
     c = 0;
     j = 0;

     while(j<N){
        scanf("%d", &Arr[j]);
        ++j;
     }

     qsort(Arr, N, sizeof(int), comparator);

     sum = fSum(Arr, N);

     for(j=0; j<N-1; j++){
        for(k=N-1; k>=j+1; k--){
           if(sum*2 == ((Arr[j]+Arr[k])*N)) {
                c++;
            }
            else{
                if(sum*2 > ((Arr[j]+Arr[k])*N))
                 break;
            }
        }
     }
       printf("%d\n", c);
     ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need the mean for all N before you start a loop to find pairs that match it.  So 2 separate while or for not all nested together.

Comment: Before you try to reduce the algorithmic complexity of your solution, it would be wise to take a minute to figure out what the algorithmic complexity of your solution *is.* Also, in problems like this, if you start with an unsorted array, you ought to consider sorting it as a first step (O(nlogn)), just to see if it helps.

Comment: Expecting floating point numbers to compare equal is always a bad idea, due to small rounding errors. Instead you should be cross multiplying. `sum(Arr) * 2 == (Arr[j] + Arr[k]) * N` is the correct way to check that the pair has the same mean as the array (using only integer math).

Comment: You also need to be careful to avoid integer overflow when computing the sum of the array. You may need to use 64-bit math, depending on the input constraints.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank all of you for your suggestions Will consider them and update my code accordingly.

Comment: @Beta, I think your suggestion makes a lot of sense. I don't have access to my system at the moment but I was just thinking about what you wrote and I believe I have a solution which will reduce the number of iterations considerably. I'll try that and revert if it worked.

Comment: @user3386109 I have modified the code in the original post. Made the following changes:

1. Checking whether the pair has the same mean as the array using integer math. 
2. Made use of quick-sort function in the c library stdlib.h to first sort the array in ascending order. Then, I ran the second loop in descending order from k = N - 1 to j+1 and breaking out of the second loop if the pair average goes below the array average. 

Do you think this can be done without nested loops? Also, any other suggestions to improve the code are most welcome.

Comment: Yes, it can be done without nested loops, but you must do some of the work yourself. *Try it with pencil and paper.*

Comment: [Socratic example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method), the sorted array is `{ 1, 4, 5, ... , 15, 18, 21 }`, with N elements, and the sum of the elements is 8N. The first pair to check is the first element and last element of the array `8N * 2 == (1 + 21) * N` which is not a match because `16 < 22`. What's the next pair that you're going to check?

Comment: @user3386109 I'm glad I'm not being spoon-fed here.  So, if you see the updated code, what the program now does and will do in the above case is it will check if 8N * 2 == (1+21)* N. Since that's not true and the average of the 2 nos is > the average of the array, the program needs to continue checking. It will now (and the answer to your question) check the pair 1 and 18. It will keep doing the same checks until the pair average either equals the average of the array (1 and 15 in the above case) or is less than it. If it's less, we discontinue checking with 1 and proceed to 4.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I missed the modification to the loops. I was expecting to see one loop, and when there were still two, I didn't look any closer. It does appear that those loops could work. The next step is to handle an array with duplicates. For example, if the array contains {1, 1, 1, ... , 15, 15} then those count as 6 pairs. Duplicates are easier (imo) if there's only one loop. I've posted an answer that demonstrates the single loop solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to problems like this is a single loop that maintains two indexes. One index starts at the beginning of the array, the other at the end. When the indexes meet in the middle, the loop is finished. In the body of the loop, the code must decide whether to update one index, or the other, or both.

For this particular problem, there are couple of additional wrinkles, which are caused by duplicates in the array.

For example, given the array `{ 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 12, 15, 15, 18 }`, there are 7 pairs. There are three 1's that can be matched with either of the two 15's, giving 6 possible pairs. The `4,12` pair is the seventh pair. So when the code finds a pair of distinct number that have the correct average, it must count the number of duplicates of each number. The number of pairs is then updated by the product of the two counts.

Given the array `{ 2, 3, 4, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12, 15 }`, there are 5 pairs. Three pairs due to the three 8's, plus two ways to pair a 4 with a 12. When the average value is present in the array, and is duplicated, one index will reach the first instance of the average while the other will reach the last. The duplicate count can be computed from the two indexes, and the number of pairs is the number of ways to choose any two of the duplicates.

Here's a sample implementation using a single loop that updates two indexes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showArray(int Arr[], int N)
{
    printf("Arr[] = {");
    if (N > 0)
        printf(" %d", Arr[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        printf(", %d", Arr[i]);
    printf(" }\n");
}

int computeSum(int Arr[], int N)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
        sum += Arr[i];
    return sum;
}

int solve(int Arr[], int N)
{
    showArray(Arr, N);
    int sum = computeSum(Arr, N);
    printf("N=%d sum=%d\n", N, sum);

    int pairs = 0;
    for (int j=0, k=N-1; k > j; )
    {
        if ((Arr[j] + Arr[k])*N > sum*2)
        {
            // the average is too high, so skip the larger value
            k--;
        }
        else if ((Arr[j] + Arr[k])*N < sum*2)
        {
            // the average is too low, so skip the smaller value
            j++;
        }
        else if (Arr[j] == Arr[k])
        {
            // handle the case where the average value is present and duplicated
            int repeat = k - j + 1;
            pairs += (repeat * (repeat-1)) / 2;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // handle the case where two distinct numbers in the array have the correct average
            // note that if there are duplicates of the numbers, the indexes are updated to the next non-duplicate
            int oldj = j++;
            while (Arr[j] == Arr[oldj])
                j++;
            int oldk = k--;
            while (Arr[k] == Arr[oldk])
                k--;
            pairs += (j - oldj) * (oldk - k);
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}

#define len(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]))

int main(void)
{
    int Arr1[] = { 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 15, 18 };
    printf("pairs=%d\n\n", solve(Arr1, len(Arr1)));

    int Arr2[] = { 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 12, 15, 15, 18 };
    printf("pairs=%d\n\n", solve(Arr2, len(Arr2)));

    int Arr3[] = { 2, 3, 4, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12, 15 };
    printf("pairs=%d\n\n", solve(Arr3, len(Arr3)));
}
```

Output from the code:

```
Arr[] = { 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 15, 18 }
N=10 sum=80
pairs=2

Arr[] = { 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 12, 15, 15, 18 }
N=9 sum=72
pairs=7

Arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12, 15 }
N=9 sum=72
pairs=5
```